# Verificar Espaço disponível em cartão SD no Android 5.1.1

Tags: android, lollipop

Preciso verificar a quantidade de espaço disponível no cartão de memória, atualmente utilizo este método para a verificação:

```
public static float megabytesAvailable() {
        File f = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        StatFs stat = new StatFs(f.getPath());
        long bytesAvailable = 0;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
            bytesAvailable = stat.getBlockSizeLong() * stat.getAvailableBlocksLong();
        }
        else {
            bytesAvailable = (long)stat.getBlockSize() * (long)stat.getAvailableBlocks();
        }
        return bytesAvailable / (1024.f * 1024.f * 1024.f);
}
```

Para versões mais antigas (até a 4.3.3) está funcionando corretamente, porém quando executo este mesmo método em um Galaxy Grand Prime Duos (SM-G531H) com a versão 5.1.1 do Android, o método acima me retorna o espaço disponível no armazenamento interno do dispositivo e não do cartão de memória. Alguém sabe o que esta errado no código?

Comment: Olá. Se você mesmo encontrou a solução, não edite a pergunta para adicionar isso nela. Você mesmo pode criar uma resposta com a sua solução (e marcá-la como aceita). Se não fez ainda, leia a [help]. :)

Comment: Obrigado Luiz, tinha até feito isso mais achei que não poderia fazer isso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei a solução no Stackoverflow em inglês:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251793/android-absolute-location-of-external-sd-card/23744167#23744167

Sendo assim alterei o método e a forma que eu pegava o cartão de memória:

```
    public static String getCaminhoSdCard() {
        String lstrDir = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");

        if (lstrDir == null || lstrDir.isEmpty())
            return "";

        if (lstrDir.contains(":"))
            return lstrDir.substring(0, lstrDir.indexOf(":"));

        return lstrDir;
    }

    public static float megabytesAvailable() {
        StatFs stat = new StatFs(getCaminhoSdCard());
        long bytesAvailable = 0;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
            bytesAvailable = stat.getBlockSizeLong() * stat.getAvailableBlocksLong();
        }
        else {
            bytesAvailable = (long)stat.getBlockSize() * (long)stat.getAvailableBlocks();
        }
        return bytesAvailable / (1024.f * 1024.f * 1024.f);
    }
```